# Passing string var across onClick

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to better understand SQLite for android and ran into an issue. My test program simply has a textbox, and button. When you enter text into the textbox and click the button I want it to create a new 'contact' (database class).

```
public class Home extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    String name = "";



    Button upButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, String name) {
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


            name = editText.getText().toString();
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView.setText(name);


        }

    });
    db.addContact(new Contact(1,name));
}
```

}

As you see when they click it saves whatever is in the textbox as name. I simply want to be able to send it down to the addContact function call. I also was a bit confused on how to use my db class inside the onClick function? Ideally I would simply like to update it inside the onClick, or would I?

Comment: why is `db.addContact(new Contact(1,name));` not in the onClick() function?

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to call it the db class inside onClick, so I was attempting to get the value from onClick and pass it to it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you write your `db.addContact(new Contact(1,name));`code line in `onClickListener`? 
If you don't want this, write a method in your `Activity`, then call it from `onClickListener`.

```
private void addContact(String name) {
    db.addContact(new Contact(1,name));
}
```

In `onCreate()` method;

```
Button upButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v, String name) {
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        name = editText.getText().toString();
        addContact(name);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be achieved in several ways, one of which would be definining your `db` variable as private.

```
private DatabaseHandler mDatabaseHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDatabaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    Button upButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, String name) {
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            mDatabaseHandler .addContact(new Contact(1, editText.getText().toString()));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code still pops errors about the onClick having @override http://puu.sh/2Tu5m/f48c61aa99.png

Comment: @Nogg, that's your code, I just copy/pasted to show the concept. If you were expecting to have a fully working code, then I am sorry to not to live up to your expectations :)

Comment: Haha, no no, thats fine! Thank you for showing me what I needed. I guess I assumed it would work as is lol.

Comment: I ended up just declaring a string inside onClick and it worked! yayyy